# Using a USB headset to make phone calls via Gmail on a Mac

Tags: mac, gmail, skype, google-talk, usb-headset

I plugged in a USB headset to my Mac, and I was able to select it in my Skype options and that worked fine. But how can I select it for Gmail to use when making calls from there? Right now, when I make a phone call from Gmail, the Mac uses the computer instead of my headset for sound input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have Google Talk open, click on settings. There should be an area that says `Input - microphone or headset` with a dropdown menu. Is your headset selected as the default device? If the sound is also not coming out of the headset, make sure it is set as the default output device too.

This is a really simple answer, but let me know if this helps!